# NEWBIE The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: windows, cmake

Trying to install a binary in Windows for use in a Python script. The installation instructions state:

HiGHS uses CMake as build system. First setup a build folder and call CMake as follows

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

Then compile the code using

```
make
```

This installs the executable bin/highs. The minimum CMake version required is 3.15.

Unsure whether "cmake .." is the exact syntax or whether the ".." is supposed to be replaced by something?  I tried it verbatim and got the error message quoted in the topic line above.  Tried "cmake [path-to-bin]" and got the same error.  I have not found CMakeLists.txt in any of the folders in the download package.

The project GitHub: https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Do you create the build folder inside of the source folder? If not that may be the reason. Personally, I prefer to provide build and source folder arguments to cmake, i.e call `cmake -S <sourcedir> -B <builddir>`. That way the structure of build and source folders is completely decoupled

Comment: Did you properly cloned the repo or where did you get the HiGHS package from? Cloning should be `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS.git` Then you can follow the instructions in the README.md file. Downloading and extracting the source packages from the release section should suffice, too.

Comment: This needs to be done with the repository root as working directory. Furthermore `make` won't do the trick, assuming the default cmake generator is a Visual Studio generator. This should probably be rewritten as `cmake -A x64 -S . -B build` and `cmake --build build --config Release` instead assuming the default generator is a VS one and you want to compile 64 instead of 32 bit...